# How to test onClick handler in React Jest + Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I know this is repeated question but the existing answers don't seem to work.
So I am using styles from SemanticUI and trying to test onClick handler on one of its HTML elements

Code for Handler :

```
        <div className="title active" onClick={(): void => handleClick(idx)}>
          <i className="dropdown icon"></i>
          {item.title}
        </div>
```

Testing for this component :

```
  const component = <Accordion items={items} />
  it('should find onClick element', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(component)
    wrapper.find('.title-active').simulate('onClick')
  })
})
```

It fails with error : `Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.`

Searching more on this issue I found out I'm not selecting the css selector correctly, which in my case I think  am.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`className="title active"` and `.title-active` will never match. Either selector should be `.title.active` or you missed dash in class name

In the future, just add `console.log(wrapper.debug())` or use debugger in IDE and check value of `wrapper.debug()` in IDE debugger's console. It prints component body as a JSX and really help with debugging in such cases.